# ScalaJS document.getElementById("editor").getAttribute("value") always returns null

Tags: javascript, scala.js

I am trying to access the value of a textarea in scalajs like so:

```
document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("input", { (e: dom.Event) =>
      console.log(e)
      console.log(document.getElementById("editor").getAttribute("value"))
    })
```

But it always returns `null`. Not sure why!

I tried the same thing in plain vanilla javascript and that seems to work just fine!

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("input", function(){
        console.log(document.getElementById("editor").value);
     });
</script>
```

I am using scalajs version 1.3.1.

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently we have to cast the results of `document.getElementById` to `org.scalajs.dom.html` elements.

In this case, before we can even add event listeners to the editor component, we need to first cast the result of `document.getElementById("editor")` to `org.scalajs.dom.html.TextArea`, like so:

```scala
val editor = document.getElementById("editor").asInstanceOf[TextArea]
```

then if we wish to access the `value` attribute of this component, we could do it like so:

```scala
editor.addEventListener("input", { (e: dom.Event) =>
    console.log(editor.value)
});
```